# Reporting services get total sum

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

I want to get the total sum of a particular column in a report. I have tried using `=Sum(Fields!baseline_number.Value)` but this gets the sum for each row and when I use

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Quantity.Value, Sum, Nothing)
```

I get the cumulative sum. I wouldn't mind using `=RunningValue(Fields!Quantity.Value, Sum, Nothing)` then getting the final value because this would be the sum for all the rows. Is there a simpler way to achieve getting the total for a certain row in a report?

Comment: Your first sentence says you want to total a column.  Your last sentence says you want to total a row.   Which is it???

Comment: I want the total column

Comment: To total a column, =Sum(Fields!MyFieldName.Value) always works for me.  I don't know why it would give you the sum of a row instead of the sum of the column.  Unless you're confusing rows with columns.

Comment: I changed it to =Sum(Fields!actual_number.Value, "ReportDataSource") and this works, I really appreciate your swift responses.